# Can someone explain why this left outer join behaves this way?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables, `item` and `item_popularity` and need to find, for a handful of items provided as input, those that have no popularity. I figured a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `NULL` check afterwards would be the right way, but I've been gettin some really weird behavior. I then modified the query a bit and got it to work but I'd really like to understand why it was behaving that way.

Let's assume those tables have these values:

```
 item
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Item 1   |
| 2  | Item 2   |
| 3  | Item 3   |
| 4  | Item 4   |
| 5  | Item 5   |
+----+----------+

item_popularity
+---------+-------------+----------+
| id_item | popularity  | id_store |
+---------+-------------+----------+
| 1       | 0.78        | 1        |
| 3       | 0.23        | 1        |
| 4       | 0.6765      | 1        |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

My original query was as follows:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item_popularity.popularity FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_popularity
ON item.id = item_popularity.id_item
WHERE item.id IN (provided input)
AND id_store = (provided store)
AND item_popularity.id_item IS NULL
```

However that would return no items, because it was only joining with items that HAD popularity, as can be seen [on this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25339f/1). I googled a bit and found lots of people with the same problem, and everywhere people were saying to move that first bit of the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN`, because the way it was it would cause the `LEFT JOIN` to become an `INNER JOIN` or something like that.

So I did that, and then the query became:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item_popularity.popularity FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_popularity
ON item.id = item_popularity.id_item
AND item.id IN (provided input)
AND id_store = (provided store)
WHERE item_popularity.id_item IS NULL
```

Now to the weird bit. Let's say I was looking for items 2, 3 and 5. I know that only 3 has a popularity score, so I should see 2 and 5 as the result, right? Well, sort of. I see 2 and 5 there, but it also lists 1 and 4 in the results! [Here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25339f/2).

Ok, so the only way I managed to get the correct results were by repeating the id filter in the `WHERE` clause, making the query this ugly looking thing, as seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25339f/3):

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item_popularity.popularity FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_popularity
ON item.id = item_popularity.id_item
AND item.id IN (provided input)
AND id_store = (provided store)
WHERE item.id IN (provided input)
AND item_popularity.id_item IS NULL
```

I don't know if I should repeat the `id_store` filter in the `WHERE`, I might just for the sake of certainty. Can anyone explain why this happens and is there a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first query did not work is not because of the condition on the LEFT table, but because you have a condition on the RIGHT table. Remove the WHERE clause entirely, in your fiddle, but SELECT all fields that you're going to use (just to see them as a debugging exercise). So, use:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item_popularity.popularity, id_store 
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_popularity
ON item.id = item_popularity.id_item
```

Once you do this, you will see that the condition     item_popularity.id_store = 1   will exclude the records thaty you see being excluded.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item.id, item.name, item_popularity.popularity
from item 
left join item_popularity 
on item.id = item_popularity.id_item
where item_popularity.popularity is null
```

You take the complete item table, add to it the popularity table where it exists and add null values where it doesn't. Then you check where the popularity has a null value (you could also check the item_popularity.id_item since that will have null values on the same rows in your given data).